# Why I am getting Unexpected token error while automating REST API in SOAP UI using Groovy

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui, web-api-testing, rest

Here is the script that I am using:

```
import.groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response==messageExchange.response.responseContext

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

assert context.FirstTestCase().getPropertyValue("contractNumber")==json.results[3].object
```

The result I am getting:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: Script3.groovy: 1: unexpected token: import @ line 1,
> column 1. import.groovy.json.JsonSlurper ^
> org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: import @
> line 1, column 1. at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:223)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
> at
> groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
> at
> groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
> at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677) at
> groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689) at
> groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:725) at
> groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:716) at
> com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
> at
> com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
> at
> com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
> at
> com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) Caused by:
> Script3.groovy:1:1: unexpected token: import at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1331)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:666)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:214)
> ... 20 more 1 error

Answer (score 0):

## Extra characters

I spotted two errors in the script.

1. Extra '.' in line 1
2. Extra '=' in line 3

Line 1 should say `import.groovy`, but you have `import..groovy`

Line 3 should say `def response=` but you have `def response==`

Comment: Thanks Terry but this solution didn't work.The result that i posted says that the error is in line 1 of the script. And I am not able to replicate why its is coming.

Comment: I don't have ''import..groovy" in the code. The script is written in the correct way. Any other solution will be welcomed.

Comment: It's in the first line of your code: `import.groovy.json.JsonSlurper`. You need to remove the '.' between 'import' and 'groovy'.